# How can I power my LEGO pneumatic engine?

Tags: pneumatic

I have just finished building a simple LPE, but have no means to power it. I live on a farm and have access to a small air compressor, would that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the compressor produces compressed air, it would certainly work, given you build adequate fittings and take precautions against overpressurization.

LEGO pneumatics have been [tested to withstand as much as 8 bars or 120 psi](http://www.autoevolution.com/news/lego-pneumatic-engines-are-availabel-for-sale-2577.html), but you definitely should plan with safety margins. If your compressor can produce higher pressures, I'd suggest building in some kind of release or auto-shutoff valve to prevent damaging the LEGO parts.

Comment: A battery of Coke-bottles pressurized to 8 bars with an outlet via a filter- and relief-valve adjusted to 3 bars might be a good idea.